# Prove $A^c \setminus B^c=B \setminus A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove $A^c \setminus B^c=B \setminus A$

**Attempt**:

let $A^c = \{ x:x \in U, x \not \in A\}$ and let $B^c = \{ x:x \in U, x \not \in B\}$ and $ B \setminus A =\{x:x \in B, x \not \in A\}$

Dont know how to proceed...?

These proofs seem to be simple but yet I do not have a good strategy for cranking out these proofs. Either my mind goes blank or I think around in circles. Im hoping it will improve via practice or perhaps mathematical talent is required?

Comment: Try writing out $A^c \setminus B^c$ as well, you could treat $A^c$ and $B^c$ as sets at first, and then switch $x\in A^c$ to $x \not \in A$ and similarly for $B$